# Update input value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, input

I am building a drum machine using AngularJS and having issues adjusting the tempo from the user interface.

I have got the object  "`this.tempo=120`" & "`<input class="bpm-input" type="number" onchange="updateBPM()" min="100" max="150" ng-model="$ctrl.tempo"></input>`"

This doesn't seem to update the `tempo` value, only the value shown in the input box.

What function would I need to update the value within the controller?

Answer (score 0):

It is normal, when you use AngularJS, you need to use the Angular WAY.

In other words, what angular do for you is the only way to do it.

AngularJS drastically control your DOM and use it as a copy.

If you change the DOM without the angular behavior, angular cannot update his copy and throws bad behaviors.

You need to use all Angular things, to tell him to apply his magic on your DOM.

Change your `onclick` attribute by `ng-click` angular directive, put your updateBPM into your controller scope, and this will works.

Hope that helps you!

Answer (score 0):

Basic things you can do are as in the attached snippet also try having Angular patterns for a manageable code base and good performance [Patterns](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#L10)

```html
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController as myCtrl">

    <input class="bpm-input" type="number" ng-change="myCtrl.updateBPM()" min="100" max="150" ng-model="myCtrl.tempo"></input>
    
 
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myController', function($scope) {
    var myCtrl = this;
    myCtrl.tempo=120;
    myCtrl.updateBPM = function(){
    alert(myCtrl.tempo);
    }    
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Code is attached below**

```
<script>
    var mainModule = angular.module('mainModule', [])
    .controller('mainCntrl', function($scope) {
      var vm = this;
      vm.tempo = 120;
    });
</script>


<div ng-app="mainModule">
  <div ng-controller="mainCntrl as ctrl">
    <input class="bpm-input" type="number" min="100" max="150" ng-model="ctrl.tempo"></input>
  </div>
</div>
```